# How is it better to organise writing data to InfluxDB with Java?

Tags: java, json, influxdb, har

There is Java EE (servlets) project.
I use Browsertime (https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/browsertime/) to get performance metrics. And this Browsertime returns .har and .json - same result but in two formats - so I need to choose which one I will use. And actually I don't need to write the whole file to InfluxDB, but only some fields that I choose.

So what is the best way to write data to InfluxDB in this situation: from which format and how? Additionally, I checked length of json - it has like 3500 lines in beautiful mode (it's about size of data).

Also, the key issue that I thought - if we'll use json and parse it - so this java class will be really big. So it would be better if we just directly streamed data to InfluxDB somehow... Maybe, there is some method of streaming data from .har to InfluxDB?

So what do you think will be good approach here to use?

Comment: HAR is actually still JSON - pick whichever is more minified and if both are the same, just filter, minify and then store

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary ok, let it be json then, but is there any method of writing json to influxdb? Haven’t seen Telegraf with java, so interesting one